# Setting up an old Mac as a remote selenium server

Tags: java, macos, selenium

So we have an old mac used for testing purposes at our testlab. We have a library of selenium test cases written in java that works when run on local browsers on my Windows 7 laptop. I want to set up the mac so that the same tests can be run remotely from my Windows 7 laptop. In short I want to set up the Windows 7 laptop as a client and the Mac as a server.

On the Windows 7 laptop I have the following code to try and connect to the remote server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    driver.quit();
}
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriverServer) and in the terminal on the Mac I can see "Selenium Server is up and running". It also says "RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub". So I guess that port 4444 has been opened up? But that's its local IP, so how do I figure out what IP to use to make the Windows 7 laptop connect to it? Once I figure out the actual address I think I should be able to connect by:

```
  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("address"), capabilities);
```

Now I don't want to open the Mac up to access from unknown devices, however the Windows 7 laptop and the Mac are both on the same network so I assume they should be able to connect through that? But I don't know how. Do I need to open the Mac up to the Windows 7 laptop specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was open the ports 4444 and 7054-5 on the Mac. After that everything just magically worked.